# Updating specific part of graph using core plot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm using `[thePlot5   insertDataAtIndex:i numberOfRecords:150];` for inserting data into the real time graph.*The graph contains  almost 10000 data points(i need 10000 points in that graph).
But i'm updating 150 data points every time.*

But   `-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot` method returns 10000 every time. so that iteration in `-(double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx` will be 20000 thousand times for together x and y.This reduces performance.

**I just want to update only the new points(i.e. 150 points not entire 10000 points)**.Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` method tells the plot to load only the new data points. In the example given in the question, the plot should ask the datasource for 150 new points, starting at data index `i`. Note that after the insert call, `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` should return the old value plus the number of new records (10000 + 150 = 10150). If you want to keep the total number of points constant, you'll need to remove some old points with `-deleteDataInIndexRange:`.

Comment: I'm using  `-deleteDataInIndexRange:` for keeping 10000 points at the graph.But my problem is to reduce iteration in `-(double)doubleForPlot:`.I only want to update new 150 points not entire 10000 points(for reducing CPU usage).How can i do that eric?

Comment: `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` will do that. Are you also calling `-reloadData` anywhere? If so, don't. That method forces the plot to reload all of its data.

Comment: I'm not using `-reloadData` anywhere.But my CPU utilisation is high when compared to when i plot 5000 points.so i assumed that core plot re plots entire 10000 data every time.Then  why CPU utilisation increases according to number of points?

Comment: The plot needs to process and draw all of the data points. The more data you have, the more work it is to draw it. 10000 points is a lot. You might look into only plotting a subset of the data that falls in the current plot area. Update the dataset if the plot ranges change.

Comment: Sorry for the repeated questions eric.its because i'm new to core-plot and objective-c.
My doubt is 150 points only updating.The total graph is already drew.Then what makes the difference if total number of points 5000 or 10000?

Comment: I'm trying to plot ECG with this(like EKG monitor).Performance and accuracy is key factor in this.
500 hz for 10 seconds(i.e. 5000 points) on that plot area and updating 150 points each time.on that time cpu utilisation is 10%.when i  changed to 500 hz for 20 seconds(i.e. 10000 points) and update same number of points(i.e. 150 points at a time).Then cpu utilisation increased to almost 20%.This is my problem.

Comment: How many of these points are visible on screen at once? No iOS device has a screen with enough pixels to display 10000 distinct points on a time series like an ECG. If you're only displaying part of the data at one time, only give that data to Core Plot. If you're displaying the whole series, perhaps filter it somehow to combine adjacent points that are close to each other. Core Plot filters out points that aren't visible before drawing, but its difficult to reduce the number of points to draw in a general way without knowing anything about the data being plotted.

Comment: That's very useful for me.Thank's for the help eric.

Comment: There is one more doubt eric.My iOs device has 1024*768 resolution.that means maximum 768 pixels is available for plot.if i plot more than 768 points actually no meaning at all.isn't it? 
Then when i plot 10000 points on the graph.the core plot filters visible points and only 768 points plotted in the plot?

Comment: If all 10000 points fall in the visible area, it will try to plot all of them. Since many data point will likely fall on the same display pixel, that's a lot of extra work for a difference you won't be able to see. A naïve filter would just skip x data points in the raw data between each one plotted (e.g., only send every 10th point to the plot). I don't know if that would work for you or if you need to do something more sophisticated.